# How can i fix this bug testn?

Tags: java, spring-boot, testng

[image: my code image]

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "com.gangoffive.birdtradingplatform.service.impl.PackageOrderServiceImpl.checkListProduct(java.util.Map)" because "this.packageOrderService" is null

    at com.gangoffive.birdtradingplatform.service.PackageOrderServiceTest.checkProduct(PackageOrderServiceTest.java:40)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at org.testng.internal.invokers.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:139)
    at org.testng.internal.invokers.TestInvoker.invokeMethod(TestInvoker.java:664)
    at org.testng.internal.invokers.TestInvoker.invokeTestMethod(TestInvoker.java:227)
    at org.testng.internal.invokers.MethodRunner.runInSequence(MethodRunner.java:50)
    at org.testng.internal.invokers.TestInvoker$MethodInvocationAgent.invoke(TestInvoker.java:957)
    at org.testng.internal.invokers.TestInvoker.invokeTestMethods(TestInvoker.java:200)
    at org.testng.internal.invokers.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:148)
    at org.testng.internal.invokers.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:128)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:848)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:621)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:443)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:437)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:397)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:336)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:95)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1280)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1200)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1114)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1082)
    at com.intellij.rt.testng.IDEARemoteTestNG.run(IDEARemoteTestNG.java:66)
    at com.intellij.rt.testng.RemoteTestNGStarter.main(RemoteTestNGStarter.java:105)
```

Please help me I `@Autowired` but it still null

Comment: Please provide your code as pasted text, not in an image. What did you try to do?

Comment: Your test program never successfully initialized the PackageOrderServiceImpl object you're trying to call .checkListProduct() on.  You need to go back in the code and find *WHERE* it should be initialized, and work backward from there to determine *WHY* it wasn't iniitialized.  I assume you mean "@Autowire" (not "Autowired"). This link might help: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-testing

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your service is `null` probably because it is missing from `ApplicationContext`. The best way to solve this changing only the test and not the code you are testing is to add a configuration subclass to your test:

```
@SpringBootTest(classes = MyTest.MyTestConfig.class)
class MyTest {
    @Autowired
    private MyService myService;
    @MockBean
    private OtherComponent otherComponent;

    //tests

    @Configuration
    static class MyTestConfig {
        @Bean
        public MyService myService() {
            return new MyServiceImpl();
        }
    }
}
```

Possibly, you need to inject dependencies on `MyServiceImpl` with field or constructor injection, but you can mock them with `@MockBean`.